# why i can't read from the pipe in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, process, pipe

I have a program where I create two children for two comparison methods (by dictionary and by length) but when I want the answer from one of the pipes (there are two pipes for each process) the function takes me out of the loop (the requirement that the loop be as long as there is input)
Program overview:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define LINELEN (80)

char *mygets(char *buf, int len);
int mygeti();

int main()
{
    // fd[0] - read
    // fd[1] - write
    char *cmpstr[] = {"lexcmp", "lencmp"};
    int veclen = sizeof(cmpstr) / sizeof(char *);
    char str1[LINELEN + 1];
    char str2[LINELEN + 1];
    int index;
    int fd1[2], fd2[2], fd3[2], fd4[2];
    if (pipe(fd1) == -1 || pipe(fd2) == -1 || pipe(fd3) == -1 || pipe(fd4) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        return -2;
    }
    switch (fork())
    { // lexcmp {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return -2;
    case 0:
        if (close(fd3[1]) == -1 || close(fd3[0]) == -1 || close(fd4[1]) == -1 || close(fd4[0]) == -1)
            perror("close other pipes");
        if (close(fd1[1]) == -1 || close(fd2[0]) == -1)
            perror("close 1");
        if (fd1[0] != STDIN_FILENO)
        { /* Defensive check */
            if (dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 -first child - STDIN_FILENO");
            if (close(fd1[0]) == -1)
                perror("close 2");
        }
        if (fd2[1] != STDOUT_FILENO)
        { /* Defensive check */
            if (dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 -first child - STDOUT_FILENO");
            if (close(fd2[1]) == -1)
                perror("close 1");
        }

        execlp("./loopcmp", "lexcmp", NULL);
        perror("execlp");
        return -2;

    default: /* Parent falls through */
        break;
    }
    switch (fork())
    { // lencmp {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return -2;
    case 0:
        if (close(fd1[1]) == -1 || close(fd1[0]) == -1 || close(fd2[1]) == -1 || close(fd2[0]) == -1)
            perror("close other pipes");
        if (close(fd3[1]) == -1 || close(fd4[0]) == -1)
            perror("close 3");
        if (fd3[0] != STDIN_FILENO)
        { /* Defensive check */
            if (dup2(fd3[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 -first child - STDIN_FILENO");
            if (close(fd3[0]) == -1)
                perror("close 2");
        }
        if (fd4[1] != STDOUT_FILENO)
        { /* Defensive check */
            if (dup2(fd4[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 -first child - STDOUT_FILENO");
            if (close(fd4[1]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
        }

        execlp("./loopcmp", "lencmp", NULL);
        perror("execlp");
        return -2;

    default: /* Parent falls through */
        break;
    }
    /* Parent  */
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd2[1]);
    close(fd3[0]);
    close(fd4[1]);
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please enter first string:\n");
        if (mygets(str1, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("Please enter second string:\n");
        if (mygets(str2, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        do
        {
            printf("Please choose:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < veclen; i++)
                printf("%d - %s\n", i, cmpstr[i]);
            scanf("%d", &index);
        } while ((index < 0) || (index >= 2));

        if (index == 0) // lexcmp
        {
            printf("you are in lexcmp\n");
            if (write(fd1[1], str1, strlen(str1) + 1) == -1)
            {
                printf("can't write str1\n");
                break;
            }
            if (write(fd1[1], str2, strlen(str2) + 1) == -1)
            {
                printf("can't write str2\n");
                break;
            }
            if (close(fd1[1]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
            char buf[80];
            read(fd2[0], buf, 80);
            if (close(fd2[0]) == -1)
                perror("close 2");
            buf[4] = '\n';
            printf("%s(%s, %s) == %s\n", cmpstr[index], str1, str2, buf);
        }
        if (index == 1) // lencmp
        {
            printf("you are in lencmp\n");
            if (write(fd3[1], str1, strlen(str1) + 1) == -1)
            {
                printf("can't write str1\n");
                break;
            }
            if (write(fd3[1], str2, strlen(str2) + 1) == -1)
            {
                printf("can't write str2\n");
                break;
            }
            if (close(fd3[1]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
            char buf[80];
            read(fd4[0], buf, 80);

            if (close(fd4[0]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
            printf("%s(%s, %s) == %s\n", cmpstr[index], str1, str2, buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char *mygets(char *buf, int len)
{
    char *retval;

    retval = fgets(buf, len, stdin);
    buf[len] = '\0';
    if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == 10) /* trim \r */
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    else if (retval)
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            ; /* get to eol */
    fflush(stdin);
    return retval;
}

int mygeti()
{
    int ch;
    int retval = 0;

    while (isspace(ch = getchar()))
        ;
    while (isdigit(ch))
    {
        retval = retval * 10 + ch - '0';
        ch = getchar();
    }
    while (ch != '\n')
        ch = getchar();
    return retval;
}

the loopcmp:
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINELEN (80)

int lencmp(const char *str1, const char *str2);
int lexcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2);
char *mygets(char *buf, int len);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int(*cmpfunc)(const char *, const char *) = NULL;
    char str1[LINELEN + 1];
    char str2[LINELEN + 1];

    if (argc != 2)
        return -1;
    
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "lexcmp"))
        cmpfunc = lexcmp;
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "lencmp"))
        cmpfunc = lencmp;
    else
        return -1;

    while (1)
    {
        if (mygets(str1, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        if (mygets(str2, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("%d\n", cmpfunc(str1, str2));
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}

int lencmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int val;
    val = strlen(str1) - strlen(str2);
    if (val < 0)
        return 1;
    if (val > 0)
        return 2;
    return 0;
}

int lexcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int val;

    val = strcmp(str1, str2);
    if (val < 0)
        return 1;
    if (val > 0)
        return 2;
    return 0;
}

char *mygets(char *buf, int len)
{
    char *retval;

    retval = fgets(buf, len, stdin);
    buf[len] = '\0';
    if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == 10) /* trim \r */
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    else if (retval) while (getchar() != '\n'); /* get to eol */

    return retval;
}
```

Expecting that after I write the strings to the pipes I will read the string I get from one of the children and print the result

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre].

Comment: You don't need to use four pipes to illustrate your problem.  If you want to ensure both directions of communication you just need to (and indeed you use only two of them) no need to illustrate things creating four processes and bidirectional communication with each.  Probably with a simpler code, you should have realized that your problem is that you close all file descriptors associated to pipes in the child, so you cannot use the pipe at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please, reduce your code otherwise is very complicated to understand it.

Then, to me it seems there are 2 issue in your code.

First, execlp() will print on stdout by default, not on the pipe. So you have to redirect it to the pipe if you want to modify that behavior.
In each child, before the execlp() add the redirection of the stdout to the pipe. For example:

```
dup2(1, fd[1])
execlp("./loopcmp", "lencmp", NULL);
```

This means you're redirdcting the strout to the pipe called fd.

Second, I'm confused about why you're using 4 pipes. You should use 2 pipes: one for every child-parent communication and then let each script (lencmpm, lexcmp) create the content to write on the associated pipe.

Comment: `execlp()` is not the issue here, `execlp` doesn't do what you say, as `execlp` doesn't have anything to do with input/output redirection. Neither `execlp(2)` or any of the `exec*()` family of system calls.

Comment: If succeed, execlp replaces the current process with the command that you specify. It will only return if it fails. Check the man page (https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) please.
So you need to redirect the stdout if you want to send the output to the parent pipe.

Comment: No, execlp replaces no process at all... the only way to create a process in unix is by means of the `fork()` system call... the `execlp()` only loads the program image of the process to the new program image, and only closes the file descriptors marked as `CLOSE_ON_EXEC`.  All the other file dscriptors remain in the same state as they were before the system call.  This can be used to provide more descriptors than the only stdin stdout and stderr, or socket opened descriptors, or whatever.  But execlp only closes descriptors that have been marked as above.

Comment: You need to do the redirection first, before the exec, of course... but that doesn't mean that _execlp() will print ond stdout by default_, this will never happen in a shell script that redirects its output to a file, or if you call the program whose child will make the redirection with the stdout already redirected.  You normally never know where the standard output is redirected or if it is at all.

Answer (score 0):

> `if (close(fd3[1]) == -1 || close(fd3[0]) == -1 || close(fd4[1]) == -1 || close(fd4[0]) == -1)`

Look at that code, if you close both file descriptors *in the same pipe,* then **you cannot use the pipe at all!!!**  And you are doing it for both, pipe `fd3` and pipe `fd4`.

You have to close only the file descriptors you are not going to use, the write descriptor in the pipe you are using to read, and the read descriptor in the pipe you will use to write.  This means that you never close both descriptors in any pipe you are going to use.  This is done in the child (as the `case 0:` label was selected, so in the parent you can only write from one descriptor and read in the other (or none, as soon as you close just one descriptor, the pipe will not be able to be written or will return 0 immediately from a read in notice of EOF)  Anyway the short circuit in the close makes that only you left one open if any of the closes fail, which is something that normally will not happen ---all of them succeed with 0 return)

If you are going to use e.g. `fd3` for output in the child and `fd4` for input, then you should, in this order,  `close(fd3[0]); close(fd4[1]);`, then `dup2(1, fd3[1]); dup2(0, fd4[0]);` to do the actual redirection to standard input and standard output, and finally you can then `close(fd3[1]); close(fd4[0]);`, you can do all the close()s at the end, but never (the ones mentioned above) before doing the actual redirection (the dups).  Now you can call `exec*(2)` in the child to load the child program.

In the parent you don't need to do any redirection, just close the descriptors you are not using (so as `fd3[1]` and `fd4[0]` are used in the child, you should close them in the parent with `close(fd3[1]); close(fd4[0]);` (this is important, as if you don't close them you will not receive the `EOF` from the other side, and will always block for input in the reading file descriptor), then write to your child on `write(fd4[1], ...);` and `read(fd3[0], ...);`.  you can reassing `int write_to_child_fd = fd4[1], read_from_child_fd = fd3[0];` to make your code more readable, if possible (but as a normal reasignment has been done and not a `dup2` call, don't close them until you are finished talking to your child, or you will not be able to use them after that.

A final note, you don't have to use this complicated example to illustrate your problem, probably you could also figure how things have to be done and create a small function to do the fork, the redirection and finally get the two descriptors out of the system.

This way you have to solve the problem for just one process, something like:

```
#define F(_fmt) "%s:%d:%s: " _fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__

#define ERR_TAIL(_etfmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, _etfmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ERR(_ecod, _efmt, ...) do {        \
        ERR_TAIL(F(_efmt), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        if (_ecod) {                       \
            exit(_ecod);                   \
        }                                  \
    } while (0) 

pid_t spawn_process(int fd[2], char *args[])
{
    int fd_down[2], fd_up[2];
    int res = pipe(fd_down);
    if (res < 0)
        ERR(1, "pipe: down: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    res = pipe(fd_up);
    if (res < 0)
        ERR(1, "pipe: up: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    switch(child_pid) {
    case -1: /* fork error */
        ERR(1, "fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    case 0: /* child process */
        dup2(0, fd_down[0]); dup2(1, fd_up[1]);
        /* now we can close all file descriptors as the pipes have
         * been successfully redirected to stdin and stdout */
        close(fd_down[0]); close(fd_down[1]); close(fd_up[0]); close(fd_up[1]);
        execlp(args[0], args);
        ERR(1, "execlp: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    default: /* parent */

        /* to be used in the calling code */
        fd[0] = fd_up[0]; fd[1] = fd_down[1];

        /* very important, see text below */
        close(fd_up[1]); close(fd_down[0]);
        return child_pid;
    } /* switch */
    /* NOT REACHED */
}
```

the importance of closing the unused descriptors in the parent process is because if you don't do it, when the communication between parent and child ends, and the child dies. the parent gets indefinitely blocked in a read, and can block in a write (once the pipe buffer fills) because there's still a side open in the other direction and so, the kernel will not signal the end of file for the reading side, nor will `SIGPIPE` the parent if it tries to write on a dead child.  So always be careful to close the pipe ends you will not use.

The code above will be used as a function that will return the two file descriptors in array `fd`, will exec the program passed in the argument list, and will return the children's pid in case of success.

In case of failure, the program simply exits with the exit code passed in the `ERR()` macro call.  But this behaviour can easily be changed if desired.